# How to evaluate this triple integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

How would I go about evaluating this integral? I want to change the order of integration but don't know how.

$$\int_0^1\int_1^{\Large e^z}\int_0^{\log y}x\ dx\,dy\,dz$$
I'm having difficulty visualing the region in order to determine another integral.

Answer (score 0):

$$f=\int_0^{\ln(y)}xdx=\frac{1}{2}\ln(y)^2$$
$$g=\int_1^{\exp(z)}fdy=-1+\frac{1}{2}\ln(\exp(z))^2\exp(z)-\exp(z)\ln(\exp(z))+\exp(z)$$
$$h=\int_0^1gdz=-4+\frac{3}{2}\exp(1)$$

Comment: how did you integrate $(\log y)^2$

Comment: @Bob: integration by parts

Answer (score 0):

First, calculate $$\int_0^{\log y} x dx$$

You will get a function, $F(y,z)$.

Then, calculate $$\int_0^{e^z} F(y,z)dy$$
to get a function $G(z)$. Calculate $\int_0^1 G(z)dz$ to get your result.

Answer (score 0):

First, I will use integration by parts to integrate $\int (\log y )^2dy$. Let $f = (\log y)^2$ and $g'=1$. Then $f' = \frac{2 \log y}{y}$ and $g = y$. So
\begin{equation}
\int (\log y )^2dy = y (\log y)^2 - 2 \int \log y ~dy = y (\log y)^2 - 2 y \log y - 2y.          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (1)
\end{equation}
Also using tabular integration we can easily get 
$$\int z^2 e^z dz = z^2 e^z - 2ze^z + 2e^z.~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (2)$$
$$\int z e^z dz = z e^z - e^z.~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (3)$$
Now we proceed to find the integration:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \int_1^{e^z} \int_0^{\log y} x~ dx~ dy~ dz &= \int_0^1 \int_1^{e^z} (\frac{x^2}{2})|_0^{\log y} dy~dz = \frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \int_1^{e^z} (\log y)^2 dy~dz\\
&=\frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 (y (\log y)^2 - 2 y \log y - 2y)|_1^{e^z} dz~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (\mbox{by} (1))\\
&=\frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 (z^2e^z - 2ze^z-2e^z+2)~dz \\
&=\frac{1}{4} ((z^2 e^z - 2ze^z + 2e^z) - 2(z e^z - e^z)-2e^z+2z)|_0^1 ~~~~~~~~~(\mbox{by} (2) ~\mbox{and}~ (3))\\
&=\frac{1}{4} (z^2 e^z - 4ze^z - 2e^z+2z)|_0^1 \\
&=\frac{1}{4}(-5e+4) = -\frac{5}{4}e+1
\end{align}